# C++: Vetor em uma função

Tags: c++, array, console

Estou fazendo um projeto onde uso muitos vetores do tipo vector. Só que trabalhar com vetores array é mais facil, por isso fiz a seguinte função:

```
// add.cpp
vector <string> sAdd (string In[])
{
   vector <string> Out;
   Out.resize (sizeof(In));

   for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(In); i++)
      Out[i] = In[i];

   return Out;
}

// add.h
vector <string> sAdd (string In[]);

// main.cpp
#include "add.h"

int main (void)
{
   vector<string> op;
   op = sAdd (string temp[3] = {
      "Opcao1",
      "Opcao2",
      "Opcao3"
});
```

Mas ocorre o seguinte erro no main.cpp: "Era esperado algum argumento em sAdd."
O que eu fiz de errado?

Nota: sou iniciante, por isso, se tiver um metodo mais facil, por favor me fale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro de tudo, você não pode usar "sizeof" pra checar a quantidade de string em um array padrão, porque a classe de string usa ponteiros e alocação dinâmica internamente. Você vai ter passar o tamanho do array na sua função:

```
vector<string> sAdd(string In[3], int size)
```

Ou então você vai ter que usar std::array.

Você não pode passar um array dessa forma, você precisa especificar o tamanho dele na sua função, ou usar um ponteiro:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


vector<string> sAdd(string* In, int size)
{
    vector <string> Out;
    Out.resize(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        Out[i] = In[i];

    return Out;
}


int main()
{
    vector<string> op;
    string arr[] = { "Opcao1", "Opcao2", "Opcao3" };
    op = sAdd(arr, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Valeu cara. Você sabe alguma forma simples de fazer  a variável arr[] existir apenas para a função. Pois se não eu teria que usar delete [] arr, que por algum motivo, sempre que eu uso meu programa fecha sozinho.

Comment: Não cara, você só precisaria usar 'delete' caso você tivesse instanciado o array com 'new'. O ponteiro é usado apenas pra referenciar o array em main sem ter que especificar a quantidade de items. E não entendi, aqui compilou normal. O seu programa não exibe nada, só copia os elementos de array comum pra um vector.

Comment: Dessa vez funcionou. Outras vezes, sempre que eu recriava o vetor normal, ele mantinha o tamanho do primeiro, mas aqui isso não acontece. Muito obrigado.